# itext pdfreader not working in unix

Tags: itext

I am reading pdf using itext pdfreader. It works fine in windows but in unix is gives an error saying PDF Header is missing. I have checked that the file is not empty and the same file is read fine by ITEXT in windows. Can someone please let me know about what could be the problem.

Comment: Works fine on Unix for me. Show us your code. Did you know that there is no `C:` drive on Unix? I am pretty sure that you are trying to read a file that is not a PDF document. See duplicate question. My guess is that the path you are using is wrong. It's Java, there is no reason why it wouldn't work on Unix. Actually, iText was originally written for use on a SUN Solaris machine.

Comment: I am using the right path, that I am sure of since I am getting the size of the file on the path along with value of flags stating whether the file is readable......

Comment: If you read the file into a `byte[]` without using iText, what are the first bytes you get?

Comment: Note that I am willing to reopen your question if you improve it. You don't share any code sample; you are not telling us which version of iText you are using; you should also show what happens when you read the file to a `byte[]` without using iText.